# My byte array length is not equal to the file .txt file size

Tags: java, byte, reader

So basically what I am trying to do is to make a JProgressBar go from 0-100% where 100% is a fully read .txt file that contains 9999 lines of words.

I am trying to do this by storing a huge string segmented into bytes into a byte array and updating the JPBar with the length of the byte array.

To my surprise, the JProgressBar stopped at 91%. Later I decided to print out the values and realized that the file length is ~10000 larger than the byte array length.

Could someone explain to me why this is the case and how can I potentially get it right? I realize that I am most likely missing a concept about reading and counting characters. The code snippet is below.

Thanks!

```
bar.setMinimum(0);
bar.setMaximum((int)file.length());

try{
     while((check = reader.readLine()) != null){

         words = words + check + "\n";
         stringCount = words.getBytes();
         bar.setValue(stringCount.length);

     }      
  }catch(Exception e){}

  System.out.println(stringCount.length);
  System.out.println(file.length());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra file contents are most likely the other part of Windows-style line endings. Standard line endings in files on Windows are `\r\n`, but your in-memory string contains only `\n`. This would accumulate a difference of 1 character per line ending, and that times 9999 lines matches the difference you're reporting.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it :)